# The text has some glitches when in camera view and when rendered [2.8]

Tags: text-editor

[image]

As you can see, the text has some graphical glitches when in camera view but when not in camera view and when the text is 2D it all looks fine. I'm not sure what the issue here is. I tried extruding the text in the text options and adding a solidify modifier.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Here is the link to just the text itself

Comment: It is hard to tell what is causing this, my guess is the objects are too small or too large. Please upload the part of the file or a file with the same problem to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/,  edit your question and paste the link.

Comment: @WhatAMesh, the link is now available, it should just be the text and the camera

Comment: Try changing "clip start" in the camera settings from 0.001m to 0.1m

Comment: @WhatAMesh Ah, I'm such an idiot, changed that when I was fiddling around with the clipping earlier. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome!